# What is "kbd"? A grey tag?

Tags: support, markdown

What is the "kbd" in Markdown?
What does "kbd" mean?
It looks like a gray tag.
<kbd>grey tag</kbd>
[Source](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54571/alternative-answer-to-what-one-has-but-eye-cannot-see)

Comment: And, the tag is unclickable, Why???

Answer (score 3):

It's not part of Markdown; it's one of the few [HTML tags that are also supported on Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#html).

> The  tag defines a keyboard input. The tag is used when it is necessary to display a text that the user should enter into the keyboard (for any number of reasons).

(source: [w3docs.com](https://www.w3docs.com/learn-html/html-kbd-tag.html))

It doesn't really have a purpose on Puzzling Stack Exchange, it's more intended for questions and answers about computer programs on e.g. [Super User](https://superuser.com). It may look nice in the question you linked to, but I'm not sure how that question looks like to visually impaired users with screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

It may look like a button to you, but as you've seen it's not clickable and should not be used to try to represent a button in a user interface. It's supposed to look like a keyboard key. So you might tell someone to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> to do something.

Using it because it's visually interesting, has a grey background, draws a box around your text etc is [considered wrong throughout SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules). You're not going to be punished for it, but someone might want to edit it out. Don't write a puzzle that depends on  using that formatting.

Comment: Sometimes, things that are *generally* considered wrong on the SE network can still be used here on this site to create fun puzzles. We're exceptional :-)